# What is the most efficient way to separate the int from this string?

Tags: c#, parsing, string

I have a string in this format: "ABC_123_"

I want to end up with and integer variable that is just the number portion of the string. What is the most efficient way to accomplish that in C#?

Comment: What can you tell us about the string format?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're worried about efficiency? The string you posted is just a few characters long, so I see no need for efficiency: any way will do fine. Unless you haven't told us an essential part of your problem. Are you working on a computer from the 80s? Is the string in reality hundred of thousands characters long?

Comment: Efficent may not have been the best word to use. I want the shortest code, not necessarily the best performance. I was using 3 lines to do this which was bugging me aesthetically.

Comment: "Concise" is the word you were looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be efficient enough. Don't sweat if it's not the most efficient unless profiling tells you that it's a bottleneck of your application:

```
string s = "ABC_123_";
int i = Int32.Parse(s.Split('_')[1]);
```

Without more information about your problem, this is what I would go with.

Answer (score 3):

Mandatory RegEx example to match all numbers in a string:

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match("ABC_123_", @"\d+").Value);
```

Change to make sure it's surrounded by _:

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match("ABC_123_", @"(?<=_)\d+(?=_)").Value);
```

Note: Value may be null/empty if your input string is in an improper format, so use int.TryParse or try/catch etc.

Comment: much better of just using `Regex.Match("ABC_123_", @"_(\d+)_").Groups[1]` instead of lookaround in this situation imo.

Comment: True, although I don't know how much different performance there is, especially when using compiled Regex.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with `int i = int.Parse(Regex.Match(string,@"\d+"));`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.  I don't know about "most efficient", but it should work:

```
int? GetJustIntPart(string original)
{
    var split = original.Split('_');
    int test;
    foreach (var item in split)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(item, out test))
            return test;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This will work no matter where the numeric part is, instead of counting on it being in a certain position.  It'll only return the *first* numeric part, though, if you have more than one.

Answer (score 0):

If the lenght of your string etc. are fixed, you can use String.Substring.

The more complicated your string gets, the more you should use Regex.

Answer (score -1):

If your string input will always be in the same form of ABC_123_ then this will work

```
int i = Int32.Parse("ABC_123_".Substring(4, 3));
```

Comment: I hope you never give this answer at an interview.

Comment: @bnaffas:  Could you provide some additional feedback?